# How to use ember select for static dropdown?

Tags: ember.js

This has to be easy, but I'm failing.

I have this in a template:

```
<select {{action 'setType' this value="target.value"}}> <!-- I've tried various things for the value -->
  <option value="0">Choice 1</option>
  <option value="1">Choice 2</option>
</select>
```

I have this in a controller:

```
setType: function(mymodel, type) {
  mymodel.set('type', type);
  mymodel.save();
}
```

The action is firing, the model is available, but none of my guesses are sending the value of the select to the controller action.

I'm using Ember 1.13.7

Comment: I set up an [ember-twiddle of this question](https://ember-twiddle.com/46c4ce256383181b9570) if anyone wants to test it out in their browser.

Comment: @MaxWallace you can show a property in the template with the value selected of the select instead of showing it in the console. It saves you from opening the console to see the results ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link your action to the event `onchange`:

```
<select onchange={{action "setType" value="target.value"}}>
```

Also, take into account that you are naming `value` the parameter that the action will receive and you aren't sending the model in that action as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a start, I'm getting the value now. But I do want the model in the action. How to send it also?